# Algorithm for the SQL 'LIKE' operator in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sql-like

I need to write a function that implements the SQL 'LIKE' operator.

For example the sql sentence:

```
  SELECT .... WHERE company_name LIKE '%soft'
```

Then I need to call my function like this:

```c
  char *company_name = "Microsoft";
  bool match = string_like( company_name, "%soft"); // must return true
```

Now, is there a predefined function in C++ that does this? If not, where can I find an algorithm or open source code for the "string_like" function?

Comment: look into `std::string` and `std::string::find` and `std::regex` and `std::regex_match`

Comment: since c++11 there is `<regex>`

Comment: please note that asking to find open source code is off-topic. You can reformulate the question to be less  suspectible to be closed for being off-topic

Comment: Essentially, it's the same algorithm as the wild card string matching, also known as globbing(?). I found an algorithm [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-pattern-matching/).